# How to repair Resharper?

Tags: resharper, resharper-4.5

I have problem with Resharper - all it's menu options are greyed, no shortcuts working...
I've tried run installer with repair option - no success
Also tried uninstall / install back - same.. :(

ReSharperSetup.4.5.1288.2.msi

Can someone advice how to make it working back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case ReSharper is listed as [Not Loaded] under Help > About Visual Studio, this most likely means that msxml6 component registration is broken. To fix this problem, just re-install MS XML Core services 6.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with VS2010 and version 5.1.1753.4 of ReSharper.  ReSharper is shown as "Not Loaded" in VS2010 About box and no ReSharper menu is visible.  After multiple install/uninstall/register MSXML6/attempts of ReSharper, I finally figured out that:

A REINSTALL DOESN'T AUTOMATICALLY RE-ENABLE RESHARPER IF IT WAS DISABLED AT THE TIME OF DEINSTALLATION!

So the simple fix is just got to Tools.Options.ReSharper.General in VS2010 and enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings

[Source](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/installation_instructions.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt help. I believe this is about shortcuts. In my case it looks my RS was disabled...

Answer (score 0):

See if it's even loaded by ticking the checkbox it in the `Tools → Add-in Manager`.